# Excel convert date time to value

Tags: excel, date, time

Date time appears as "Tue Nov 09 2021 20:27:51 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
How to convert to a value that I can use to calculate time difference between two dates?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show the difference in time(hours) or days?
For days you can use a column with the following formula

```
=CONCAT(MID(A3,9,2),"-",MID(A3,5,3),"-",MID(A3,12,4))
```

where A3 is your cell containing the string "Tue Nov 09 2021 20:27:51 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)". This will be converted to 09-Nov-2021. You can then use a normal subtraction (A-B) to calculate the day difference between 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use MID:

```
=MID(REPLACE(A1,11,0,","),5,21)-TIME(5,0,0)
```

Then format it how you would like.

[image]